# Setting signInAudience using azure graph API -- Invalid JSON

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api, azure-cli

I try to set the signInAudience using the Azure Graph API (with the azure cli / az rest command) from inside powershell using the following code:

```
$body='{"signInAudience":"AzureADAndMicrosoftAccounts"}'
echo $body
Test-Json -Json $body
az rest --method PATCH --uri https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications/$application_object_id --body $body --headers "Content-Type=application/json"
```

Which should (according to the rest documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)) Update the signInAudience auf the Azure AD Application.

This is the result:

```
{"signInAudience":"AzureADAndMicrosoftAccounts"}
True
ValidationError: Bad Request({
  "error": {
     "code": "BadRequest",
     "message": "Unable to read JSON request payload. Please ensure Content-Type header is set and payload is of valid JSON format.",
     "innerError": {
     "date": "2020-10-13T10:48:48",
      "request-id": "f29fd020-33aa-4cda-b98e-130d1434cd85",
      "client-request-id": "f29fd020-33aa-4cda-b98e-130d1434cd85"
     }
   }
 })
```

Why does this not work?
Other Changes can be set ussing this API, the following call does for example work.

```
az rest --method PATCH --uri https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications/${azuread_application.main_application.object_id} --body '{"api":{"requestedAccessTokenVersion": 2}}' --headers "Content-Type=application/json"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to my test, if we enclose the entire string in  single quotation, the Azure CLI command `az rest` will not identity double quotation. It just identity the body as `{signInAudience:AzureADAndMicrosoftAccounts}`. So I suggest you use double quotation to enclose the entire string.
[image]

Besides, when you want to allow users with a personal Microsoft account, or a work or school account in any organization’s Azure AD tenant to access the application, the `signInAudience` should be set as `AzureADandPersonalMicrosoftAccount`. For more details, please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/application?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties).
[image]

for example

```
 $body="{'signInAudience':'AzureADandPersonalMicrosoftAccount'}"
  az rest --method PATCH --uri https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications/<object id> --body $body --headers "Content-Type=application/json"
```

Comment: You are right the json formatting did not work as I did expect it.